# Is there an equation to find the intersection of 3 circles without complex steps?

Tags: algorithms, circles

Is there a way to find the intersection 3 circles without substituting and solving the equations into each other? The reason is because I am making a trilateration program, so I won't really be able to solve the equations in code.
The centers of the circles and their radii will be given.

I have this equation

```
x = (pow(r1,2)-pow(r2,2)+pow(i,2))/(2*i);
y = -1 * sqrt(pow(r3,2)-pow(x,2))+j;
```

where r1,r2,r3 are the radii of the 3 circles
and i is the length of the area and j is the width, but I don't see how this really works without the centers of the circles

Comment: Are you looking for the _points_ of intersection or the common area bounded by the circles? In the latter case, what do you mean by "length" and "width" of the area, given that it is obviously not going to be a rectangle?

Comment: @Zen I need the point where they all intersect. I don't think my equation really works

Comment: If you don't know anything about the circles other than the radius, it's not possible (because you can shift a circle of constant radius around in space - radius is not sufficient to determine a circle). Is there anything else you know? Can you explain more clearly what i and j are?

Comment: @Zen We also know the centers of the circles, ignore those equations, they don't work

Answer (score 1):

In general, three circles in the plane
do $not$ have a common point.
I am not sure what you mean by
"the intersection 3 circles".

This is because two circles have at most two points
in common
(unless they are the same circle).
A third circle is very unlikely to pass through
one of these points.

Algebraically,
since the equation of a circle
with radius $r$
and center $(a, b)$
is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = r^2$,
you are trying to solve
three equations
($(x-a_i)^2+(y-b_i)^2 = r_i^2$
for $i=1, 2, 3$)
in two unknowns
($x, y$).